# Let $G$ be a setf of $\mathbb{R}$ such that that...

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question that
Let $G$ be a nonempty set of $\mathbb{R}$ such that that $\inf G = \sup G$. Prove that G has exactly one element.
My approach is that
let a,b $\in$ $G$

$\inf G \leq a \leq b \sup G$
then it's contradiction.

Is this correct proof or do I need to add anything to make more formal?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your argument, how is $a\leq b\sup G$?

Comment: He means if $a,b$ are distinct, WLOG $a<b$ then $\inf G \leq a < b \leq \sup G$ or $\inf G < \sup G$

Comment: You want to say $a \lt b$, not $a \leq b$, but otherwise your proof is correct.  Another way to say it without needing a proof by contradiction is:  Suppose $a, b \in G$  Without loss of generality, $a \leq b$.  Then $\inf G \leq a \leq b \leq \sup G$, so $\inf G = \sup G$ implies equality holds throughout.  Since $a, b$ are arbitrary elements of $G$, this means any two elements of $G$ must be equal to one another, so $G$ can have only one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect on several grounds.

First, you have only shown, at best, that $|G| \ge 2$ implies that $\inf(G) \ne \sup(G)$. You have not properly shown that if $G = \{a\}$ then $\inf(G) = \sup(G) = a$.

Secondly, what you should say is

> "Let $a,b$ be distinct elements of $G$, and, without loss of generality, assume $b \ge a$."

At this point then your argument is valid. Otherwise, you have issues with the cases of $a \ge b$ not working within your argument. And, indeed, what if $a=b$? That distinctness is somewhat necessary to state as well since, after all, if $G = \{a,b\}$ and $a=b$ then $\inf(G) = \sup(B)$ after all since $G$ is a singleton (but then why even bother stating two elements?). (And of course this means that you could modify the above statement to a strict inequality since $a,b$ are distinct.)

Comment: Is it necessary to show single element in the set implies supremum and infimum coincide? OP didn't ask for an iff argument?

Comment: I'm not really sure that works. I get where you're going insofar as the contrapositive goes, but I don't think that "this doesn't hold for all $G$ where $|G|\ge 2$" necessarily implies it does hold for the case where $G$ is a singleton. It just doesn't quite seem right, like there's something left missing in such an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Perhaps you meant to assume instead that
$$\inf G \leq a < b \leq \sup G?$$

Now use the fact that $\inf G=\sup G$.

Comment: Can the quick downvoter care to explain his/her vote?

Comment: That person downvoted mine too which involved a similar argument, hence I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct and there i don't think you can make it more formal. Below is the complete version.

If there are indeed two elements in $G$, WLOG assume that $a< b $. Then $\inf G \leq a < b \leq \sup G$ or $\inf G < \sup G$ contradicting our initial assumption that $\inf G =\sup G$